# SQL Server Query - Sorting data using Order By in Union All

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-order-by

Here's the sample data, this table summarized the sales of one tenant in 5 years and per month. Also, the total sales, average sales per month and per day are computed. to be able to do this I have used 4 sql query to get the

1. Per Month and per year sales,
2. Total Sales,
3. Average Sales Per Month, and
4. Average Sales Per Day

Then, I used the UNION ALL method to produce this kind of output:

[image]

Here's the part of the code

```
SELECT tenantcode, MONTH, year1, year2, year3, year4, year5
from #SalesPerYear 
UNION ALL
SELECT * FROM #TotalSales 
UNION ALL
SELECT * FROM #AveSalesMonth 
UNION ALL 
SELECT * FROM #AveSalesDay
ORDER BY TENANTCODE
```

Each temp table corresponds to each query to get the mentioned each query set above.

But this only produce an output in a SINGLE TENANT only, what I want is to make it flexible by making it multiple tenant selection, I was able to do it but the ordering is not pleasing. **The desired output is to be something like this**

[image]

But the actual output is **NOT ACHIEVED**. the Tenant1 ordering is okay, **but the tenant2 is rumbled.**

something to this

[image]

I hope I explained it well enough.

Comment: You should have a look at `Grouping Sets` instead of your current approach: https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb510427%28v=sql.100%29.aspx

Comment: is this doable in sql server 2008?

Comment: Well, i linked the 2008 manual :-)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can add a faux column in all queries that identify the type of row (per year, total, monthly average and daily average2). Then sort the combined result by tenant, row type and month number, in that order:

```
SELECT 1 AS [row type], tenantcode, [month], year1, year2, year3, year4, year5 FROM #SalesPerYear
UNION ALL
SELECT 2, #TotalSales.* FROM #TotalSales
UNION ALL
SELECT 3, #AveSalesMonth.* FROM #AveSalesMonth
UNION ALL
SELECT 4, #AveSalesDay.* FROM #AveSalesDay
ORDER BY tenantcode, [row type], [month]
```

You can convert month name to number using `DATEPART(MONTH, 'January 1, 2000')` or month number to name using `DATENAME(MONTH, '2000-1-1')`.

#### Alternate solution

Since the results should be ordered by the month column in this order: JAUNARY, ..., DECEMBER, TOTAL, AVE/MONTH, AVE/DAY. You can simply use a nested query and a lengthy `CASE` statement:

```
SELECT * FROM (
    SELECT tenantcode, [month], year1, year2, year3, year4, year5 FROM #SalesPerYear  UNION ALL
    SELECT * FROM #TotalSales    UNION ALL
    SELECT * FROM #AveSalesMonth UNION ALL 
    SELECT * FROM #AveSalesDay
) AS foobar
ORDER BY tenantcode, CASE [month] 
    WHEN 'JANUARY'   THEN 1
    WHEN 'FEBRUARY'  THEN 2
    WHEN 'MARCH'     THEN 3
    WHEN 'APRIL'     THEN 4
    WHEN 'MAY'       THEN 5
    WHEN 'JUNE'      THEN 6
    WHEN 'JULY'      THEN 7
    WHEN 'AUGUST'    THEN 8
    WHEN 'SEPTEMBER' THEN 9
    WHEN 'OCTOBER'   THEN 10
    WHEN 'NOVEMBER'  THEN 11
    WHEN 'DECEMBER'  THEN 12
END
```

There are a couple of ways to simplify the case statement but I would rather keep it readable.

Comment: i need to put rowtype?

Comment: Month is not numeric based on the query set of #SalesPerYear. it is actually based on the month name and the code goes like this Order by DATEPART(MM,datename(month,date)+' 01 2011')

Comment: the Month name is not in right order sir... as you have said because in my current code, it is not in number

Comment: you need 2 "helper columns" one for the "rowtype" as suggested here, but another for sorting the months properly too; you simply will not succeed without both. Note that the column headed "month" also has non-date information in it (such as "TOTAL") that's why I suggest another helper column

Comment: this is the error: ORDER BY items must appear in the select list if the statement contains a UNION, INTERSECT or EXCEPT operator.

Comment: Considering your suggestion to revise the first query, but I really want my sorting in sql (backend) be in Name ordering , because it will be used as source in my Crystal Report

Comment: It worked, only thing I did not like is that it created two additional columns instantly, I am really considering your first suggestion. Is it possible to make my month into number for easy sorting and display in in month in the final query to be displayed?

Comment: thanks so much for the effort! for you what is the most efficient approach to use since both is working, performance wise?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/92150/discussion-between-salman-a-and-rickyprogrammer).

Answer (score 1):

Can you please try this

```
select * from 
(
SELECT tenantcode, MONTH, year1, year2, year3, year4, year5
from #SalesPerYear 
UNION ALL
SELECT * FROM #TotalSales 
UNION ALL
SELECT * FROM #AveSalesMonth 
UNION ALL 
SELECT * FROM #AveSalesDay
)t  
ORDER BY TENANTCODE
```

Comment: Oh... 

Also to inform that I have added just one column in order by clause, if wanted to order on more column, the last last line should have been
order by TENANTCODE,MONTH. Though ordering by month will order alphabetically. To keep it in exact order of month, you might need to case statement to give some  number value to month in inner queries and then ordering on that number in outer query.

Comment: To add a sequence to month you might user query like this:
SELECT tenantcode, 
case MONTH
  when 'january' then 1
  when 'february' then 2
  when 'march' then 3
  when 'april' then 4
  when 'may' then 5
  when 'june' then 6
  when 'july' then 7
  when 'august' then 8
  when 'september' then 9
  when 'october' then 10
  when 'november' then 11
  when december' then 12
end as 'mn', year1, year2, year3, year4, year5
from #SalesPerYear 
order by tenantcode,mn